# No Device found Flutter VSCode Emulator

Tags: android, debugging, visual-studio-code, flutter

I'am using memuPlayer as an emulator and it was working perfect

but out of sudden now VSCode can't read any emulators :

I've tried  : memuPlayer , NoxPlayer , BlueStack

and all of them is enabled usb debugging

here is the result of `flutter doctor`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.5.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[X] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.26.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

last thing I've tried to put `"--enable-software-rendering"` in args

Comment: why don't you use android emulators. Just asking

Comment: taking much memory and cpu and very laggy

Comment: what dart version are you using. you should run the app using `flutter run--preview-dart-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Deleting SDK 28.0.2 and installed SDK 27.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I Faced Same Issue in Android Studio and I Replaced Flutter SDK With the latest Version and it's Working Fine For Me.

Flutter SDK link: https://flutter.io/sdk-archive/#windows

Comment: have u download the beta version or the Dev version ?

Comment: beta Version 0.5.1